# How can I set caps lock to a more complex keystroke?

Tags: macos, caps-lock, keyboard

In the Keyboard settings, it is possible to set Caps Lock to other modifier keys, but it doesn't allow to put in a custom keystroke.

Is it possible to set it to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>?

I'm using OS X Lion 10.7.3 if that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 5):

### [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html)

allows to change the caps lock key behavior. It's mac software, even tough the name may not suggest it :).

[image]

(pic from developer's website)