# Remap the 'UpperCase' key

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set caps lock to a more complex keystroke?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/how-can-i-set-caps-lock-to-a-more-complex-keystroke)

I lost the tab key on my macbook and since i rarely use the uppercase key i'm wondering if it is possibe to use it instead by remapping or else?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyKZd.jpg

I installed KeyRemap4Macbook but can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In general, remapping a modifier key to another modifier key is relatively simple; Apple provides a system preference pane to do it. Remapping a standard key to another standard key is slightly more complicated, but easy enough by editing or creating a keyboard layout. The tricky part is converting a modifier key to a standard one, or vice versa. For that, you need a specialized program.

You will need a System Preference Pane called [PCKeyboard Hack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html).

First, go the the **Keyboard** preference pane, select the **Keyboard** tab, and click the **Modifier Keys...** button. In the resulting sheet, set **Caps Lock Key** to **No Action**.

[image]

Then, install **PCKeyboard Hack**.

In the preference pane it installs, go to **Caps Lock**, select "Change Caps Lock", and set the key code to 48 (the key code for the tab key).

Instructions on a related question are [available on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x).